# Create HUD in Sprite Kit that remains static on screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I'm trying to create a static HUD that stays at the top of the screen throughout the game in a jump game from this tutorial. I'm still new to Swift, so maybe it's a convention I don't see easily:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87232/make-game-like-mega-jump-sprite-kit-swift-part-2

In the tutorial, he puts the HUD in the `override init(size: CGSize)` function:

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

 override init(size: CGSize) {
      super.init(size: size)
    ...

   // Build the HUD

   // HUD
   hudNode = SKNode()
   hudNode.zPosition = 1000
   addChild(hudNode)


   // Coins
   // 1
   let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "powerup05_1")
   coin.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: self.size.height-100)
   coin.zPosition = 1000
   hudNode.addChild(coin)

  // 2
  lblCoins = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
  lblCoins.fontSize = 70
  lblCoins.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
  lblCoins.position = CGPoint(x: 375, y: self.size.height-100)
  lblCoins.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
  lblCoins.zPosition = 1000

  // 3
  lblCoins.text = String(format: "X %d", GameState.sharedInstance.coins)
  hudNode.addChild(lblCoins)

  // Score
  // 4
  lblScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
  lblScore.fontSize = 70
  lblScore.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
  lblScore.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width-325, y: self.size.height-100)
  lblScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Right
  lblScore.zPosition = 1000

  // 5
  lblScore.text = "0"
  hudNode.addChild(lblScore)
 }
```

However, if I try to use this function in my game I get an error:

`Argument labels '(fileNamed:)' do not match any available overloads`

In this function:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   switch gameState.currentState {
   case is WaitingForTap:
   gameState.enterState(WaitingForBomb)
   // Switch to playing state
   self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(2.0),
    completion:{
      self.gameState.enterState(Playing)
  })

  case is GameOver:
  // Error! Argument labels '(fileNamed:)' do not match any available overloads
   let newScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
   newScene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
   let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
   self.view?.presentScene(newScene!, transition: reveal)

   default:
   break
  }
}
```

So I've resorted to putting it in the `override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)`, but the HUD moves once the player jumps up:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
 ....
// Build the HUD

// HUD
 hudNode = SKNode()
 hudNode.zPosition = 1000
 addChild(hudNode)


// Coins
// 1
 let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "powerup05_1")
 coin.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: self.size.height-100)
 coin.zPosition = 1000
 hudNode.addChild(coin)

// 2
 lblCoins = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
 lblCoins.fontSize = 70
 lblCoins.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
 lblCoins.position = CGPoint(x: 375, y: self.size.height-100)
 lblCoins.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
 lblCoins.zPosition = 1000

 // 3
 lblCoins.text = String(format: "X %d", GameState.sharedInstance.coins)
 hudNode.addChild(lblCoins)

 // Score
 // 4
 lblScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
 lblScore.fontSize = 70
 lblScore.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
 lblScore.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width-325, y: self.size.height-100)
 lblScore.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Right
 lblScore.zPosition = 1000

 // 5
 lblScore.text = "0"
 hudNode.addChild(lblScore)
}
```

Comment: Is your game scene subclassing SKScene?  GameScene: SKScene {...}

Comment: Yes. My code looks like this: `class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {`

Comment: Is it possible to upload the code to github? I can't find an error in the part you have posted here

Comment: How are you doing camera stuff for this game?  Are you making your own virtual camera or using the new sprite kit features?

Comment: @Stefan I've uploaded a private repo to BitBucket. If you send me an email address I can invite you to the repo.

Comment: @J.Doe I'm pretty sure it's using new Sprite Kit features. I didn't write the game, I'm just trying to augment it. If you can send me an email address I can invite you to the private repo so you can take a look.

Comment: @WangYudong just sent an invite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding your `hudNode` to the `cameraNode` makes the HUD move together with the camera so that it will look static on screen. That is to change `addChild(hudNode)` to `cameraNode.addChild(hudNode)`.

Then use [convert(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483056-convert) to change the point from the current scene coordinate to the `cameraNode` coordinate. That will set HUD's position in the new coordinate with just a little modification. For instance, change `coin.position` like this:

```
coin.position = convert(CGPoint(x: 300, y: self.size.height-100), to: cameraNode)
```

Do the same thing to the other HUD:

```
lblCoins.position = convert(CGPoint(x: 375, y: self.size.height-100), to: cameraNode)
lblScore.position = convert(CGPoint(x: self.size.width-325, y: self.size.height-100), to: cameraNode)
```

The result after those 4 lines modification:

[image]

Comment: Wow. I would have never figured that out. Swift is still really new to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using the addChild() function is indeed better than setting hudNode.position = camera.position.

Comment: @jmcmahon443 Yeah, but you were close!

Comment: @WangYudong Sorry, I didn't award your bounty. i will have another bounty for this question in a few days:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663151/collect-coins-and-add-to-score-label-in-sprite-kit